# Login and different keyboard layout

Tags: login, keyboard-layout

I set up a server remotely accessible via ssh, without any DE. My password contains some characters that are not present in a standard US keyboard, however they can be typed using deadkeys. When I access the server via ssh, there is no problem since, on the client side, I've already logged in and so I can choose whatever keyboard layout I like.

Now I want to access the server directly, not remotely, (since I'm having problem with ssh), but with the US key, I cannot select different keyboard layout before the log in.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What OS? How are you accessing the server "directly"?

Comment: Access the server via `ssh`, possibly from a laptop while standing in front of it, and change the keyboard layout as `root`? E.g. on Linux, `loadkeys` etc.

Comment: I cannot access via ssh, because, for some reason ssh server has stopped. So I have to connect a keyboard and a screen to  my server and to work with them. This is what I mean by "directly".